# Is there a way to get a second set of Thieves Guild Armor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I am looking for another set of thieves guild armor in skyrim on the Xbox. I have found the hood, gloves, and boots but need the body armor. Also I have gotten the full set from the fence in the thieves guild. Is there any other way aside from the fence to get the armor?

Answer (score 3):

There are various pieces of the thieves guild set around the Ragged Flagons cistern area in the ratway. Check around shelves and in the training rooms, Etc.

Comment: I found the gloves, boots,and hood but I need the armor do you know where it would be in the training room

Comment: Also worth noting that [this area respawns by the usual rules](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Respawning) so in theory you could get as many copies of the item set as you like, even without using mods or the console